# how to change image onclick javascript function?

Tags: jquery, image, function, onclick, onchange

I got a problem, I tried several times but result is always same, I don't know what's wrong with my code. If you click on right image, it will change to left image, but if you click on left image, it wont change to right image, why?
here is code:

```
    function changeImage() {

    if  (document.getElementById("changer").src == "imgs/left.gif")
    {
        document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/right.gif";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/left.gif";
    }

}
```

and image src code here:

```
<img  src="imgs/right.gif" id="changer" onclick="changeImage()"/></a>
```

I need this function: 
click on (right arrow image), then it'll change to (left arrow image)  and click on same (left arrow image) again will return to default, (right arrow image).

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: The only change that you have to do is to check if the src contains "imgs/left.gif" or not > 'if(document.getElementById('changer').src.indexOf('imgs/left.png') != -1)'. This should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by Prabu in his answer that the actual src is **absolute path** but not relative path.

To solve this:

- Pass the element object i.e **this** as argument to the function.
- Create a variable **bln** inside the element object i.e `element` in that function.

---

```
<img src="imgs/right.gif" id="changer" onclick="changeImage(this)" />
                                                             ^ pass the element object
```

---

```
 function changeImage(element) {
     element.src = element.bln ? "imgs/right.gif" : "imgs/left.gif";
     element.bln = !element.bln;  /* assigns opposite boolean value always */
 }
```

The above function will toggle the image src's without depending on the value present inside the `src` property.

**[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yytW/1/)**

BTW, You can also do this using just CSS:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yytW/43/)**

Comment: @Amin You are posting the answer which we had shown you. Instead you should mark a post as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hey problem is you mentioned `foldername/filename` but document.getElementById("changer").src giving `fullpath` like C:\Users\ws21\Desktop\imgs\right.gif

For example

```
 function changeImage() {

//its checking C:\Users\ws21\Desktop\imgs\right.gif=="imgs\left.gif"
        if  (document.getElementById("changer").src == "imgs/left.gif")
        {
            document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/right.gif";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/left.gif";
        }

    }
```

**So it always execute else part only**

Comment: Your code is like my above code, right arrow will change to left arrow, but left arrow wont change to default (right arrow) check it here (http://behdasht.co/wp/new.php)

Comment: hey i explained clearly..in if condition its checking with fullpath like C:\Users\ws21\Desktop\imgs\right.gif is equal to imgs\left.gif.so it always execute else part.initially u gave "imgs/right.gif" so is changed to imgs/left.gif

Comment: Still u have any doubt?

Comment: Hey, you are right, Now solved.. Thanks for your sharing. I should've used fullpath.. thanks a lot.. PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$("#changer").click(function(){
    imagePath = $("#changer").attr("src");
    if(imagePath == "http://behdasht.co/wp/imgs/left.gif"){
        $("#changer").attr("src", "http://behdasht.co/wp/imgs/right.gif");

    }else{
        $("#changer").attr("src", "http://behdasht.co/wp/imgs/left.gif");
    }
});

//Updated to use jquery completely
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8hGWZ/

http://jsfiddle.net/8hGWZ/2/ (Full jquery)

Comment: there is something wrong here, your code is working well, but not working in my page (http://behdasht.co/wp/new.php)

Comment: @Amin : Check the updated source code. This will work for you. Cheers

Comment: I told you, its still same, this code work singly, but not in this page. you can check it again. thnx

Comment: @Amin, can you clear cache, cuz in your website , the image changing works for me.. :(

Comment: @Amin do accept or vote-up the answer which you found that helped you..:).. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeImage() {
    var src = document.getElementById("changer").src;   
var imgsrc = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
if  (imgsrc == "left.gif")
{
    document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/right.gif";
    console.log('if'+document.getElementById("changer").src);
}
else 
{
    document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/left.gif";
    console.log('if'+document.getElementById("changer").src);
}
```

}

USE THE ABOVE SHOULD WORK

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pVGNe/)**

Comment: I would at first discourage the use of inline JS

Comment: I did it, but still same, I mean, right arrow will change to left, its ok, but changed left arrow image wont change to default..

Comment: Finally we found a code to work on this page, but can you tell me what is these following errors in your code? Message: 'console' is undefined
Line: 116 and Line Line: 111

Answer (score 0):

What you've got should work.

Here's a shorter version:

```
function changeImage() {
    this.src = this.src == "imgs/left.gif" ? "imgs/right.gif" : "imgs/left.gif";
}
```

Comment: I paste your code , still result is same, check it out pls (http://behdasht.co/wp/new.php)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXss8/)

**HTML**

```
<a/>
<img src="imgs/right.gif" id="changer" onclick="changeImage(this)" />
</a>
```

**js**

```
i=1;
function changeImage(el) {
    el.click=++i;
    el.src = ((el.click)%2 == 0) ? "imgs/right.gif" : "imgs/left.gif";
}
```

Comment: Your code is working well , but when I use your code, my page doesn't work, Your code is just working without another codes. here is the page: (http://behdasht.co/wp/new.php)

Answer (score 0):

Hey try complete path for the images in the javascript like

```
if  (document.getElementById("changer").src == "http://mydomain.com/imgs/left.gif")
{
    document.getElementById("changer").src = "http://mydomain.com/imgs/right.gif";
}
```

Some browsers use complete url in src

Or u can check this

```
  <img  src="http://behdasht.co/wp/imgs/right.gif" id="changer" onclick='javascript: this.src = this.src == "http://behdasht.co/wp/imgs/left.gif" ? "http://behdasht.co/wp/imgs/right.gif" : "http://behdasht.co/wp/imgs/left.gif";'/>
```

Comment: You can check it through this link: (http://behdasht.co/wp/new.php) still its same, I really got tired to solve this problem.

Comment: Now I edited. U can try the script inside the onclick function itself. It is a reference problem for changeImage function. Try the edited part now

Comment: Sorry try now, I changed to what u needed

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM IS SOLVED. HERE IS COMPLETE ANSWER:
WE SHOULD USE FULL PATH OF IMAGE URL OTHERWISE IT WONT WORK.

```
 function changeImage() {
    if  (document.getElementById("changer").src == "HTTP://YOURDOMAIN/left.gif")
    {
        document.getElementById("changer").src = "HTTP://YOURDOMAIN/right.gif";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("changer").src = "HTTP://YOURDOMAIN/left.gif";
    }

}
```

Especial thanks to Prabu Parthipan

THERE IS ANOTHER METHOD :

```
<img src="imgs/right.gif" id="changer" onclick="changeImage(this)" />
```

if we use (this) , then no need to use full path of image url.
In this case I should say thanks to MR GREEN ... !

Comment: You are comparing again with the image paths. Don't depend on image paths for a simple toggle. Using relative paths is always preferred. Check my answer again.