# changing image on click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the image while clicking on that current image.

For example, for the expanding and collapsing process, I want to change the **plus(+) button** to **minus(-)** and vice versa.

Please help me with coding. I want to do it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function changeImage() {

    if  (document.getElementById("changer").src == "imgs/plus.png")
    {
        document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/minus.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("changer").src = "imgs/plus.png";
    }

}
```

Img source code here

```
<img  src="imgs/plus.png" id="changer" onclick="changeImage(this)"/></a>
```

Comment: I already use this code. But its not working for me.. Is any scripts to be declare? for example, jquery.js, jquery.min.js like this?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You need to call this function. Also, please change the src according to your image names.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: You can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502734/how-to-change-image-onclick-javascript-function

Answer (score -1):

**HI now try to this way**

**Now try to** `class` and define your `class` `background` `image` **as like this**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.imgChange').on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('up');
    });  

});
```

```css
.imgChange{
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:79px;
  height:79px;
    cursor:pointer;
  background:url('http://salesmomsnetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/PlusMinus.gif') no-repeat -67px -15px;
}

.imgChange.up{
background:url('http://salesmomsnetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/PlusMinus.gif') no-repeat -67px -122px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgChange up"></div>
```

Comment: i just need images for 9 x 9 size

Comment: you crop the image and apply accroding to you design and now chagne to width or height .imgChange class