# Change Icon on click and add a css class through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a expandable h3. For that I'll have a "plus" image to click and when it's clicked has to change to a "minus" image and I need to add a css class to the h3 to show the content. I'll paste all the code below:

```
<div class="default">
    [ManageBlog]
    <div class="msearch-result" id="LBSearchResult[moduleid]" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <div class="head">
        <h1 class="blogname">
                [BlogName] <img src="/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/plus_symbol.png" alt="Plus Button" id="ExpandBlogDescriptionImg"></h1> [RssFeeds]
        <br style="line-height: 12px; clear: both" />
        <h3 class="blogdescription">
                [BlogDescription]</h3> [Author]
    </div>
    <br /> [Posts] [Pager]
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $("#ExpandBlogDescriptionImg").click(function() {
         var right = "https://train.fitness/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/plus_symbol.png";
         var left = "https://train.fitness/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/minus_symbol.png";
         element.src = element.bln ? right : left;
         element.bln = !element.bln;
     });
     var img = $("#ExpandBlogDescriptionImg");
     if (img.src = "https://train.fitness/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/minus_symbol.png") {
         $('.blogdescription').addClass("ExpandBlogDescriptionText");
     } else {
         $('.blogdescription').removeClass("ExpandBlogDescriptionText");
     };
 });
```

Comment: what is `element.bln`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change image onclick javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502734/how-to-change-image-onclick-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1):

you can use .attr function of jquery to set image source like

```
$('.img-selector').attr('src','plusorminusimagepath.jpg');
```

and you can have a boolean flag to know if it is less or more

Comment: use ' prop ' instead of ' attr '. it is deprecated.

Comment: Hi Ranjeet, can you please share the link where it is stated that .attr is deprecated ?

Comment: it is best practice to use prop() instead of attr().     https://www.google.co.in/search?q=.attr+is+deprecated&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=kI49V8j2LfLI8AeiyJagAg#q=attr+vs+prop

Comment: thanks but I think best practice and deprecation are two different things

Answer (score 0):

Here i was changing `alt` attribute of image tag on click. the same way you can change src

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $("#ExpandBlogDescriptionImg").click(function() {

     if ($(this).attr("alt") == "+") {
       $(this).attr("alt", "-");
     } else {
       $(this).attr("alt", "+");
     }
   });
   var img = $("#ExpandBlogDescriptionImg");
   if (img.src = "https://train.fitness/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/minus_symbol.png") {
     $('.blogdescription').addClass("ExpandBlogDescriptionText");
   } else {
     $('.blogdescription').removeClass("ExpandBlogDescriptionText");
   };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="default">
  [ManageBlog]
  <div class="msearch-result" id="LBSearchResult[moduleid]" style="display: none">
  </div>
  <div class="head">
    <h1 class="blogname">
                [BlogName] <img alt="+" src="/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/plus_symbol.png" alt="Plus Button" id="ExpandBlogDescriptionImg"></h1> [RssFeeds]
    <br style="line-height: 12px; clear: both" />
    <h3 class="blogdescription">
                [BlogDescription]</h3> [Author]
  </div>
  <br />[Posts] [Pager]
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: It is saying that jQuery is not defined. But it is loaded at the very beginning of the page. How can I fix it?

Comment: it might be possible that your url is not correct or file is not available at location

Comment: Now the images are working but the css class is not added. I mean, it is added always but has to be added if the image is the minus and has to be removed if the image is the plus. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ExpandBlogDescriptionImg").click( function(e){
    var right = "https://train.fitness/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/plus_symbol.png";
    var left = "https://train.fitness/portals/40/Images/Train_Fitness_2015_S/images/minus_symbol.png";
    if($(e.currentTarget).attr('img') == left){ 
      $(this).hide();
      $(e.currentTarget).attr('img',right);
    }else{
      $(this).show();
      $(e.currentTarget).attr('img',left);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sprite image and CSS, else when you click and it will load another image, for some time between image would disappear.

HTML

```
<div class="head">
        <h1 class="blogname">
            [BlogName] <span class="plus icon"></span></h1>
        [RssFeeds]
        <br style="line-height: 12px; clear: both" />
        <h3 class="blogdescription">
            [BlogDescription]</h3>
        [Author]</div>
    <br />
```

CSS

```
.icon{
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   display:inline-block;
   background-image:url(plus-minus-sprite-image.png);
}
.icon.plus{
   background-position:20px center;
}
.icon.minus{
   background-position:40px center;
}
```

JS

```
$('.icon').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("plus minus");

     if($(this).hasClass("plus")){
         $('.blogdescription').addClass("ExpandBlogDescriptionText");   
     }else{
         $('.blogdescription').removeClass("ExpandBlogDescriptionText");
     }
     // Or $('.blogdescription').toggleClass("ExpandBlogDescriptionText");
});
```