# Multiple image change on click (similar to Cargo image gallery scrub)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-gallery

I am trying to replicate Cargo's image gallery scrub using my own HTML/CSS and/or Java. Example of what I want here on image click: https://sage-smith.com/. It is similar to this stack thread (which worked in my code): [how to change image onclick javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502734/how-to-change-image-onclick-javascript-function)

However, this solution only offers to click between 2 images. I am trying to do it with multiple images (like an image gallery).

This is what I have so far:

HTML

```
 <a><img src="collage3.jpg" id="changer" onclick="changeImage(this)"/></a>
```

Javascript

```
  function changeImage(element) {
     element.src = element.bln ? "collage3.jpg" : "asset-2.png";
     element.bln = !element.bln;  /* assigns opposite boolean value always */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to change only 2 images you can add some style by displaying none and block in css

simple example:

```
<div onclick="yourFunction()">
  <img src="url" style="display: none" class="img1"/>
  <img src="url" style="display: block" class="img2"/>
</div>

 
// js

function yourFunction(){
  //here is you need to add style for img1 like  display block aaa img2 is 
  //display none !
  document.querySelector(".img1").style.display = 'block'";
  document.querySelector(".img2").style.display = 'none'";

  //if you need to back images on click again you can do it by false and  true 
}

//this is a simple code that i thought
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you preload your images. Have an array of image sources, and then create a new array of images that you can then loop through. In this example I've used [a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) to manage this operation.

Have a container for each image set. Attach a listener to it. The function that we reference in `addEventListener` actually returns a new function that will be used as a handler when the event is triggered. We pass in the container, an id, and the image set that it is going to be responsible for.

Inside `handleClick` we initialise `index` which is the current index of the array. We set the initial image in the container, and then increase `index` ready for the next click.

The closure (the function returned by `handleClick` does the work. When a click is triggered it checks `index` to see if it's exceeded the length of the array (in which case it resets `index` to 0), and then updates the image, finally increasing `index` for the next round.

```js
const data=[["https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ad40ad/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/454545/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/789acc/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/994563/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff456/000000"],["https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ad40ad/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/454545/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/789acc/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/994563/000000","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff456/000000"]];

// Returns a new array of images from
// the source array
function loadImageSet(arr) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    const set = arr.map(src => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = src;
      return img;
    });
    res(set);
  });
}

// Returns a nested array of images
function preload(data) {
  return Promise.all(data.map(loadImageSet));
}

async function main(data) {
  
  // Get the images
  const images = await preload(data);

  // Cache the containers
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('div');

  // For each container add a listener. `handleClick`
  // does some initial setup (using the id, and image set),
  // and then returns a new function that is called
  // when `click` is triggered
  containers.forEach(c => {
    const { id } = c.dataset;
    const imageSet = images[id - 1];
    c.addEventListener('click', handleClick(c, id, imageSet), false);
  });

};

// Call the main function
main(data);

// Accepts an id and an image set
function handleClick(container, id, imageSet) {

  // Initialises the array index
  let index = 0;

  // Initialises the first image
  container.appendChild(imageSet[index]);
  
  // Increases the index
  ++index;

  // Return the function that is called when
  // the click event is triggered
  return function () {

    // Reset `index` if it hits the `imageSet` length
    if (index === imageSet.length) index = 0;

    // Replace the image with the next one in
    // in the `imageSet` array
    const img = container.querySelector('img');
    img.replaceWith(imageSet[index]);

    // Finally increase `index`
    ++index;
  }

}
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; height: 100px; width: 100px; }
div:hover { cursor: pointer; }
img { height: 100px; width: 100px; }
```

```html
<div data-id="1"></div>
<div data-id="2"></div>
```

Comment: hey @andy! thank you for getting back to me. so this worked when i plugged it into my code, however, i am trying to target specific div classes, this code targets all div tags. how do i achieve that? here is my test site - [link] (https://pauline-esguerra-2.superhi.com/).

Comment: `const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');` (where `myClass` is the class you're using) should be sufficient. Just make sure that the length of the images array matches the number of containers you have. @PaulineEsguerra

Comment: "make sure the length of the images array matches the number of containers you have." how do i do this? ie if i have three containers, what do i change in the code?

Comment: You make sure that your images array has three nested arrays. In my example there are two, one for each container.